# MySql Basic table creation/handing

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a simple table where I insert field and I do some checks in MySql. I've used Microsoft SQL relatively easy. Instead, MySql give evrrytime query errors without even specifying what's going on. Poor MySql software design apart, here's what I'm trying to do:

1 table with 4 fields with an autoincremental autogenerated number to det an ID as primary key

```
 CREATE TABLE `my_db`.`Patients_table` (
`ID_Patient` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`Patient_name` VARCHAR( 200 ) NOT NULL ,
`Recovery_Date` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
`Recovery_count` INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

a simple stored procedure to insert such fields and check if something exist before inserting:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nameInsert(IN nome, IN data)
INSERT INTO Patients_table (Patient_name,Recovery_Date) values (nome,data)

 IF (EXISTS (SELECT Recovery_count FROM Tabella_nomi) = 0) THEN
 INSERT INTO (Patients_table (Recovery_count)
ELSE
SET Recovery_count = select Recovery_count+1 from Patients_table
END
```

this seems wrong on many levels and MySQL useless syntax checker does not help.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: I think you should atleast read the basics of MySQL [Create Procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) and [Insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) statements. And don't blame something you didn't even tried to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a lot wrong with this block of code. (No offense intended!)

---

**First**, Procedures need to be wrapped with `BEGIN` and `END`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nameInsert(IN nome, IN data)
BEGIN
    ...[actually do stuff here]
END
```

---

**Second**, since your table is declared with all fields as `NOT NULL`, you *must* insert all fields with an `INSERT` statement (this includes the `Recovery_Date` column, and excludes the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column). You can add `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to the date column if you want it to be set automatically.

```
INSERT INTO Patients_table (Patient_name,Recovery_Date) values (nome,data)
```

---

**Third**, what exactly is your `IF` predicate doing?

```
EXISTS (SELECT Recovery_count FROM Tabella_nomi) = 0
```

If you want to check if a row exists, don't put the `= 0` at the end. Also, `Tabella_nomi` isn't declared anywhere in that procedure. *Also*, your `SELECT` statement should have a `WHERE` clause, since I'm assuming you want to select a specific row (this is going to select a result set of *all* recovery_counts).

---

**Fourth**, the second `INSERT` statement seems a little messy. It should look more like the first `INSERT`, and keep the point I made above in mind.

```
INSERT INTO (Patients_table (Recovery_count)
```

---

**Fifth**, the `ELSE` statement

```
SET Recovery_count = select Recovery_count+1 from Patients_table
```

Has some problems too. `SET` is meant for setting variables, not values in rows. I'm not 100% sure what your intent is from this statement, but it looks like you meant to increment the `Recovery_count` column of a certain row if it already exists. In which case, you meant to do something like this:

```
UPDATE Patients_table SET Recovery_count = Recovery_count+1 WHERE <conditional predicate>
```

Where the conditional predicate is something like this:

```
Patients_name = nome
```

---

Try these things, and look at the errors it gives you when you try to execute the `CREATE STATEMENT`. I bet they're more useful then you think!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and don't worry, no offense at all. I'm learning SQL and MySQL it's normal to make some mess.

 Recovery counts it's just a counter I'm going to increment with a MAX(Recovery_count)+1 everytime that patient gets medical treatments (this is just an example, not a real situation, the whole scenario is invented).

Replying to your points one by one.

First:
Yeah, I copied a bad version of the code. The actual code had a BEGIN and END.

Second:
OK

Third:
Recovery count it's a counter. It's gonna be incremented everytime so I check if in first place it exists otherwise

Comment: I set it to 1.
Third:

Comment: Fourth:
OK

Fifth:

Yeah, my bad. UPDATE is what I need in case of a previously existing Recovery_count.

I'll try the suggestions and let you know